# How to trigger mvn install during package of a different project?

Tags: java, maven

I have a "commons" library that I install to my local repo using `mvn install`. That library provides common company stuff used in different, not connected projects.

So I include that library as a maven dependency. And when I run `mvn package` on the final projects, there have been days where I forgot that I have to explicit install the commons library to get the changes picked up during `package` of the implementation projects.

Is there any chance I could trigger/invoke `install` of a different project during package?

Comment: You should start to use a repository  manager where you do this only once and than it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `Antrun` maven plugin, and execute shell command using ant while running properr lifecycles of maven build.
Here you have some details on configuration
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

If repository manager or external scripting (Ant) is not an option you could tweak your project structure. You could introduce an aggregator maven project which will run modules in a predefined order:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
...
<modules>
    <module>[path to commons project]/commons</module>
    <module>[path to your module project]/module</module>
</modules>
```

So whenever you want to build your project you build this aggregator project instead.